# Differential equations help: $x=y'+\sin y'.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i have the equation $x=y'+\sin y'.$

To solve this I put $y'=p$ and $x=p+\sin p.$

$dx=(1+\cos p)dp\;$ and $\;dy=dx\cdot p=p+p\cos p$

To find $y$ I integrate this and I have $\;p^2/2+p\sin p+\cos p$.

But the answer on my book is $x=p\cdot \ln p + \sin p+ p\cdot \cos p.$

Answer (score 1):

I understand the logic of your solution, but it gives $y=p^2/2+p\sin p+\cos p+C$, not "$x=\dots$". Let's tighten up the notation by introducing the function $f(p)=p+\sin p$. Since $f$ is strictly increasing, it has an inverse $g=f^{-1}$. The equation you have amounts to $y'=g(x)$. The solution of this equation is indefinite integral $y=\int g(x)\,dx$.

Although $g$ isn't an elementary function, it can be integrated by substitution $x=f(p)$, $dx=f'(p)\,dp$. Indeed, 
$$\int g(x)\,dx = \int p\,(1+\cos p)\,dp = p^2/2+p\sin p+\cos p+C \tag1$$
which is the same thing you got. 
The formula for $y$ in terms of $x$ would be 
$$
y=(g(x))^2/2+g(x)\sin g(x)+\cos g(x)+C 
\tag2$$
although the fact that $g$ is not an elementary function makes (2) unpleasant to look at.

I don't know what the formula $x=p\cdot \ln p + \sin p+ p\cdot \cos p$ means, but I suspect that $p$ does **not** stand for $y'$ here. Because a formula for $x$ in terms of $y'$ is the equation you are given: $x=y'+\sin y'$.

Comment: Thank you.So my solution is right? maybe the book is wrong..